The subscript on orbitals give equations for nodal planes
I've just learned about orbitals and I have noticed a peculiar pattern. If you take the subscript of the orbital name say in dx²-y² you take x²-y² and set it equal to 0. x²-y² = 0
It ALWAYS gives a graph of all the nodal planes combined. Even in dz² which uses a shorthand z² for 2z²-x²-y² as I've found out. My teacher seems to not know about this. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

The names of the orbitals were chosen precisely for this reason.
